# Calling web service from c++ v6

Tags: c#, vba, vb.net, web-services, ms-access

i have been  deploy webservice in vb.net .

is there will be any problem if i will cal the webservice from c++ (version 6) or 
  Microsoft Access  VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not trivial in the languages you mention. We use a different route:

- create a web service
- create a .NET client which calls the webservice, and make it a COM exposed dll
- use COM calls from the legacy code to the .NET COM client

In this way you have all the advantages of the .NET framework at your disposal, and the changes in the legacy code are simple.

The major disadvantage is that you have to register the COM dll on the client PC, or use the side-by-side mechanism in Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gSoap library (http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/) to consume web service in C++, but its not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730836(VS.80).aspx) on calling web services from VB6 - VBA is almost identical to VB6, so I expect the advice still applies.